# Windows security policy analysis tool

Tags: windows, audit

I have several security policy files (INF exported from different Windows machines) which I need to audit.
Is there any automatic tool you know of, that can analyse those files according to best practice that I'll provide?

Comment: I would do this with C# as a Desktop app, just make a list of threats and loop thru the files, and the practice can be made within template ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Security Baseline Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7558) and [Security Compliance Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/cc835245.aspx) are Microsoft's tools for this.

SCM is likely the one you are looking for...

Comment: MSBA I know, and it can't check exported policy files.
SCM I know a bit less, and I couldn't find automatic way for analysing INF files in t as well. Google didn't help.

Currently importing the settings to VM and then running MSBA, but surly there is better solution than that...