# Using "Security Compliance Manager" to audit a Windows system

Tags: windows, audit, hardening

I found a few posts which suggest using Microsoft SCM (Security Compliance Manager) to audit the security of Microsoft software solutions:

- [Windows security policy analysis tool](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/17806/7)
- [How do I apply a security baseline to Windows 2008 R2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2159/7)
- [IIS and SQLServer Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/2346/7)

Here's a sample screenshot of SCM, showing "261 unique settings" for Windows 7 SP1 computer security:

[image: SCM screenshot]

What I don't get is how these "unique settings" are **audited**. I mean, SCM seems to simply report all hardening options, rather than checking (auditing) whether they are applied to Windows.

So far, I found the following way to (automatically) audit the settings:

1. Export them (using the panel to the right of SCM) as [SCAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Content_Automation_Protocol) XML files.
2. Use a tool such as [OVAL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ovaldi/) or [jOVAL](http://joval.org/) to audit the system against the exported XML files.

Along the same lines, I use the following approach to apply a baseline:

1. Export the baseline (or a customization thereof) as a GPO.
2. Apply the GPO.

My question is:

> Can SCM audit the settings itself, so that I don't have to export XML files and then use 3rd-party tools?

Answer (score 2):

SCM itself does not audit or apply settings. Settings are applied by importing a GPO backup in to AD and reported on by importing a DCM in to SCCM (no relation to SCM despite the similar abbreviation).

There is documentation that describes how it all works under "attachments" for each baseline.

Comment: There's a lot of acronyms here that not everybody may be clear on. Can you expand on it?

Comment: Here's the non-TLA version: Security Compliance Manager itself does not audit or apply settings. Settings are applied by importing a Group Policy Object backup in to Active Directory and reported on by importing a Desired Configuration Management format, exported from the Security Compliance Manager Console, in to SCCM.